# Can anyone identify this song from Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind?

Tags: music-identification, nausicaa-of-the-valley-of-the-wind

In *Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind* at about 49:48, a sort of techno-electric music plays that I find really enjoyable. Problem is, I cannot find this anywhere on the internet, or even in the official soundtrack of Nausicaa. Could someone help me identify it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Sci-Fi Stack exchange, what an interesting first question. Unfortunately I can't help you, but I've made an edit to your question to try and help answers stay on topic. To learn what is or isn't on topic, take a look at our [tour] and [help]. Enjoy your stay on the site!

Answer (score 2):

The soundtrack for Nausicaa of the Valley of the Wind was composed by Japanese composer Joe Hisaishi. There are various different dubs of the film (even a terrible US re-edit called Windriders I believe) and there may be slight differences between the different dubs. That said the majority of the soundtrack appears to be on Spotify and/or Apple Music

https://open.spotify.com/album/1qHmdiWzKzuDWtEa1gQEW4

[https://music.apple.com/us/album/nausicaä-of-the-valley-of-the-wind-original-soundtrack/881802202](https://music.apple.com/us/album/nausica%C3%A4-of-the-valley-of-the-wind-original-soundtrack/881802202)

According to Wikipedia numerous version of the soundtrack have been released.

The film's score was composed by Joe Hisaishi, while the vocal theme song "Kaze no Tani no Naushika" was produced by Haruomi Hosono (Yellow Magic Orchestra and Happy End member) and sung by Narumi Yasuda.[54] Numerous soundtracks and albums relating to the film have been released.[55]

> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Image Album - Bird Person (風の谷のナウシカ イメージアルバム 鳥の人) released 25 November 1983
>
> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Symphony - The Legend of Wind (風の谷のナウシカ シンフォニー 風の伝説) released 25 February 1984
>
> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Soundtrack - Toward the Far Away Land (風の谷のナウシカ サウンドトラック はるかな地へ) released 25 March 1984
>
> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Drama Version - God of Wind (風の谷のナウシカ・ドラマ編) released 25 April 1984
>
> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Best Collection (風の谷のナウシカ BEST) released 25 November 1986
>
> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Hi-tech Series (風の谷のナウシカ・ハイテックシリーズ) released 25 October 1989
>
> Nausicaä of the Valley of Wind: Piano Solo Album  released 15 March 1992

Somewhere in all this I suspect you should be able to pinpoint the piece you are looking for.

Comment: Given the fact that it's a techno-sounding track, I'm going to guess it's in the Hi-Tech series. Thanks!